# NTFS volume recognised as "Unallocated Space" but works with Windows

Tags: partitioning, windows, mount, ntfs, disk

Moving to Ubuntu, I have a drive with windows on a drive with Ubuntu on and 4 other ntfs drives

3 of which appear fine in both systems
1 however works fine on windows (single ntfs volume) but in ubuntu the drive appears in the disk utility with a 134 MB "Microsoft Reserved Partition" and 2TB of Unallocated Space

Is there any way I can get this volume to be mounted in Ubuntu with out moving all my data to another driver formatting and then moving back again

Answer (score 0):

you can install ntfs configuration tools from ubuntu software to auto mounte ntfs volume , also ntfs partition can be writable with using this good tool, dont forget that after installation, open terminal and write "sudo mkdir -p /etc/hal/fdi/policy"